# how to write an interface for such an object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a complex object which shows:

```
const styles = {
       base: {
           position: 'absolute',
           userSelect: 'none',
        //    backgroundColor: '#4323ba'
       },
       top: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '10px',
        top: '-5px',
        left: '0px',
        cursor: 'row-resize'
       },
       bottom: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '10px',
        bottom: '-5px',
        left: '0px',
        cursor: 'row-resize'
       },
       left: {
        width: '10px',
        height: '100%',
        left: '-5px',
        top: '0px',
        cursor: 'col-resize'
       },
       right: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '10px',
        right: '-5px',
        top: '0',
        cursor: 'col-resize'
       },
       topLeft: {
        width: '20px',
        height: '20px',
        top: '-10px',
        left: '-10px',
        cursor: 'nwse-resize'
       },
       topRight: {
        width: '20px',
        height: '20px',
        top: '-10px',
        right: '-10px',
        cursor: 'nesw-resize'
       },
       bottomLeft: {
        width: '20px',
        height: '20px',
        bottom: '-10px',
        left: '-10px',
        cursor: 'nesw-resize'
       },
       bottomRight: {
        width: '20px',
        height: '20px',
        bottom: '-10px',
        right: '-10px',
        cursor: 'nwse-resize'
       },
     }
```

I tried to wrote like this:

```
interface IPosition<T> {
   width: string,
   height: string,
   cursor: Cursor[T]
}
enum Cursor {
top = 'row-resize',
bottom = 'row-resize',
left = 'col-resize',
right = 'col-resize',
topLeft = 'nwse-resize',
topRight = 'nesw-resize',
bottomLeft = 'nesw-resize',
bottomRight = 'nwse-resize'
   }
interface IStyle {
    base: object,
    [propName: string]: IPosition<propName>
}
```

I can not continue writing `IStyle`...
Apparently I cannot refer the type parameter T in IPosition with Cursor.
I am a new bee with typescript.
I want to practice writing precise `typings` and  don not want to use `any` to bypass it.But I can not really figure out a better way for this.
Hope anyone may give me some suggestions.
Thx.

Comment: Could you please paste the code of what you tried not a picture, and the full IStyle interface you tried.

Comment: I have pasted the code I wrote.

Comment: Do you need to use `cursor: 'col-resize'` could you use `cursor: Cursor .topLeft` instead ?

Comment: I know I can use Cursor.topLeft, however there are two many position, I wonder if I can write just one attribute for these positions, like I update in IStyle...

Comment: We can use a mapped type to write a single line for all Cursors, `type IStyle = {base: object} & { [P in keyof typeof Cursor]: IPosition<typeof Cursor[P]> }` but if we want to constrain `cursor` it will have to be a value of the enum when you create the object not a string `interface IPosition<T extends Cursor> {
    /*...*/
    cursor: T
}`

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for your patience. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a value of a property as a type parameter. That's not quite what the type system is made for. The types specify what possible values a property can have (and yes, you can restrict to specific string values); they are not designed to specify specific values.

Another problem is the mixture of a specified property with a mapped type. In this case the additional property must be of the same type as the mapped property. The solution is to specify the properties individually.

You can define these types to fully type your data structure:

```
enum Cursor {
    top = 'row-resize',
    bottom = 'row-resize',
    left = 'col-resize',
    right = 'col-resize',
    topLeft = 'nwse-resize',
    topRight = 'nesw-resize',
    bottomLeft = 'nesw-resize',
    bottomRight = 'nwse-resize'
}

interface Position {
   width: string;
   height: string;
   cursor: Cursor;
}

interface LeftPos {
    left: string;
}

interface RightPos {
    right: string;
}

interface TopPos {
    top: string;
}

interface BottomPos {
    bottom: string;
}

interface Style {
    base: { [key: string]: string };
    top: Position & TopPos;
    bottom: Position & BottomPos;
    left: Position & LeftPos;
    right: Position & RightPos;
    topLeft: Position & TopPos & LeftPos;
    topRight: Position & TopPos & RightPos;
    bottomLeft: Position & BottomPos & LeftPos;
    bottomRight: Position & BottomPos & RightPos;
}
```